# Swipedown on sidebar menu not working on iPhone using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I am facing a strange problem, I am unable to swipedown the sidebar menu on my website, but if I swipe the other content of the page then it works fine, even I am able to swipeup the menu, but it does not work for swipedown.

Comment: What do you mean by "swipedown"? Is it okay for you to share that link? If it is, which label do we check?

Comment: i mean to say to scroll down the page, if you scroll it by touching the sidebar menu then it would not work, but it works on the rest of the page, please try the given link on Iphone

Comment: Is it reproducible only with an Apple device? Seems okay on Android. In which case, shouldn't there be such a mention in the main question? And a tag perhaps?

Comment: I have deleted an external link from this question to highlight that it was off-topic. If you wish to show a problem with JavaScript, create a Stack Snippet or a JS Fiddle.